SQL Server converting datetime type to unexpected date
I am working on a project for school where I need SQL Server to generate the create statement for Cypher (Neo4j).
I have in SQL Server a table Transfers where I need the column DATETIME from (of type datetime).
The output I get from
select DATETIME 
from TRANSFER

is in this format: 2004-05-04 00:00:00.000
But when I write the following script in SQL Server to create the Cypher statement I get:
select concat('create (t:Transfer {datetime: ', DATETIME, '});') 
from TRANSFER

the output is as follows: create (t:Transfer {datetime: May  4 2004 12:00AM))});
I am unable to figure out why this is happening.

EDIT and solution
I found out that, as the comments suggested, i did not explicitly tell SQL Server which format i wanted it to be.
Therefore it decided on it's own and since i used concat() which creates a String it got converted to the unexpected string value of the date.
I solved it by converting the datetime value to a string value in the format i wanted it to be.
The code and output are as follows:
select concat('create (t:Transfer {datetime: ', convert(varchar(25), DATETIME, 120), '});') 
from TRANSFER

create (t:Transfer {datetime: 2004-05-04 00:00:00});

You know dates and datetimes are not stored in a display format right? They are displayed in a binary format. So unless you specify the format when trying to use it as a string you will get some default date format. I suggest you use convert with the appropriate code for the format you want.

This is expected, you are asking for implicit conversion, and for an English based language that's the format MMMM [ ]d yyyy hh:mmAM/PM if you want a specific format, use CONVERT to convert it to a varchar with a style code.

But the thing i miss probably is how it is that when selecting the same column it outputs two different datetime formats, one as: 2004-05-04 00:00:00.000 and the other as: May  4 2004 12:00AM
I select in both cases the same DATETIME column, and do nothing to it (besides perhaps the concat?)

Defaults are often different for different use-cases...

@DaleK The simple answer here is that the first version isn't doing any conversion, it's the client app which is displaying it. Dates aren't text, they are binary values. In the second version, an implicit conversion is happening, and CONVERT should be used instead witha style parameter  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

But there is no client app in this case, both are run in SQL Server, on the samen table on the same column (the DATETIME column which is of type datetime)
So eventhough there is nothing changing i need to convert a datetime value to datetime?

@DaleK i wanted to but since the question was closed i did not see the option to do so.
-- feel free to delete this comment as it has nothing to do with the question

@Diorcula - If you wish to preserver fractional seconds, you can use format 121 instead of 120.
